# virtuoso sparql engine

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I'd like to ask if anyone knows how a sparql query is actually executed in virtuoso opensource edition. Is the sparql query mapped to an sql query? How the RDF data are accessed?
Should I read the source code for this?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: You could start with Virtuoso's documentation, specifically the [white papers](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/white-papers/), because white papers usually describe how the product works.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the sparql query mapped to an sql query?

Yes, it is

> How the RDF data are accessed?

You can find some details on rdf-data storage here: [Implementing a SPARQL compliant RDF Triple Store using a SQL-ORDBMS](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSRDFWP)

But if you are writing RDF-aware app you should just use the SPARQL interface and ignore all implementation details. It's fast and feature-rich.

> Should I read the source code for this?

Well, it depends on what you need to achieve. It's not necessary for usage, but if you are planning to provide patches then reading source is a must :)

Comment: the links that you provided are dead. Can you provide the new ones ?